# How to have wcf datacontract class to have a field of an object of another datacontract class

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF DataContract class as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class Breads
{
    public Breads() { }

    public Breads(int breadid, string breadname, int specieid)
    {
        breadId = breadid;
        breadName = breadname;
        specieId = specieid;
    }

    private int breadId;

    [DataMember]
    public int BreadId
    {
        get { return breadId; }
        set { breadId = value; }
    }

    private string breadName;

    [DataMember]
    public string BreadName
    {
        get { return breadName; }
        set { breadName = value; }
    }

    private int specieId;

    [DataMember]
    public int SpecieId
    {
        get { return specieId; }
        set { specieId = value; }
    }

    private Specie.Species specie;

    [DataMember]
    public Specie.Species Specie
    {
        get
        {
            if (specie == null)
            {
                BLL_HIS.Classes.Animals.Specie s = new BLL_HIS.Classes.Animals.Specie();
                s = s.SelectById(specieId);
                specie = new Specie.Species(s.SpecieId, s.SpecieName);
            }
            return specie;
        }
    }


}
```

as you can see there is a property named Specie which is an instance of another class that is describe as follows:

```
    [DataContract]
public class Species
{
    public Species() { }

    public Species(int specieid, string speciename)
    {
        specieId = specieid;
        specieName = speciename;
    }

    private int specieId;

    [DataMember]
    public int SpecieId
    {
        get { return specieId; }
        set { specieId = value; }
    }


    private string specieName;

    [DataMember]
    public string SpecieName
    {
        get { return specieName; }
        set { specieName = value; }
    }

}
```

when i leave out the property Specie the code work just fine. Although it compiles and runs with the property, when i invoke it, an error occurs. The error text is as follows:

*Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.*

**The error details is a follows:**

```
*The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IBread.SelectById(Int64 id)
   at BreadClient.SelectById(Int64 id)
Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)*
```

notes:

1- I tryed to fill the Specie manually to make sure that the problem is not with that method, and the "underlying connection" is not relate to sql connection.

2- I tried to use "KnownType(typeof(Species))" attribute for my Breads class.

By the way, Sorry for the length of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DataMember]
public Specie.Species Specie { get; }
```

Currently you only define a `get` property. It must also define a `set` operation to be deserialized.

"The connection was closed unexpectedly" is probably an unhandled exception from the deserializer on the service side. If you turn on WCF logging, you'd be able to see the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ErnieL, that was one of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have two problems, the first one as was solved by ErnieL (All DataMembers must have both set and get operations)

and the other one which solve my problem was, apparently all the services have to be in the same namespace, I had some folders and each service with it's relevant stuff were in that folders, I removed those folders and place all services in one folders then it works!!